# Refresh or Update the listadapter from a fragment in android eclipse

Tags: android, fragment, adapter, listadapter, android-side-navigation

I have a MainActivity with some fragments to run when click on side navigation menu. In the side navigation menu there is a item Called Number of SMS that shall be updated as soon as in the other fragment you choose the desired phone number. but the problem is I do not know how to refresh the list adapter from that fragment. I defined a class called allvalues which contains all my global variables. The variable responsible for SMS count is allvalues.NumberOfLocations
here is the code of MainActivity:

```
    package com.faraz.locatecar;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public static ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    public static  ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    public static NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    String passString;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    MyDb dbf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        allvalues.context = this;

        if(!allvalues.setno){
            Toast.makeText(allvalues.context, "Please choose a number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dbf = new MyDb(allvalues.context);
        String phoneNumbers = dbf.trakersCount();
        // to check if there is any phone numbers or not
        if(phoneNumbers.matches("0")){
            Toast.makeText(allvalues.context, "Please save a number first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, allvalues.NumberOfLocations));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // Traker number choose
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, phoneNumbers));
        // add tracker number
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            new SmsBased().execute();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new OldListReader();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new ShowEveryThing();
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new ChoosePhoneNumber();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new NewTrakerRegister();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            final String MyPref = "mypref";
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyPref, 0);
            if(prefs.getBoolean("FirstRun", true)){
                prefs.edit().putBoolean("FirstRun", false).commit();
                fragment = new PasswordFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                passString = allvalues.pass;
            }else{
                passString = dbf.passString();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
                setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // Async part
    private class SmsBased extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(allvalues.context);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Please wait ");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("SMS sending is in progress");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            allvalues.send_command = SmsManager.getDefault();
            String SendChangedPassword = "where," + passString + "#";
            allvalues.send_command.sendTextMessage(allvalues.PhoneNumberToSend, null, SendChangedPassword, null, null);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            Toast.makeText(allvalues.context, "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();          
        }
    }       


}
```

and this is the other Fragment which in this fragment, the phone numbers already user, saved are going to be showed in a list which on click of the number, first the number will be selected and then the allvalues.NumberOfLocations should be updated which equals to the number of received messages for the selected number.

```
package com.faraz.locatecar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ChoosePhoneNumber extends Fragment {
    private static int i;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.choose_number, container, false);

        allvalues.AllPhones_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        MyDb phonechoose = new MyDb(allvalues.context);
        phonechoose.readTrakers();
        allvalues.showphones = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listphone);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(allvalues.context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, allvalues.AllPhones_list);
        allvalues.showphones.setAdapter(adapter);

        // just added from here
        allvalues.showphones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {
              final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
              allvalues.PhoneNumberToSend = item;
              Toast.makeText(allvalues.context, "شماره :" + allvalues.PhoneNumberToSend, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              allvalues.setno = true;
              SMSNumbers();
              Fragment fr = new HomeFragment();
              FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
              fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fr).commit();         
            }

          });
        // till up here


        return view;
    }
    public void SMSNumbers()
    {

        Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cursor = allvalues.context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "address", "date", "body"},null,null,null);
        if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while  (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
               String address = cursor.getString(1);
               if(address.equals(allvalues.PhoneNumberToSend)){
                   i++;
               }
        }
        }
        allvalues.NumberOfLocations = i + "";
        Toast.makeText(allvalues.context, allvalues.NumberOfLocations, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

but the number in the inside the navigation drawer does not update...
I also tried to call the navigation adapter after the line:
allvalues.NumberOfLocations = i + "";
but it did not work...
please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a custom listener in your fragment like this :

```
public interface FragmentListener {
    void refreshData();
}
```

and declare a variable for this listener in your fragment :

```
private FragmentListener listener;
```

and in your onItemClickListener:

```
listener.refreshData();
```

now create a method in your fragment to set this listener:

```
public void setListener(FragmentListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

finally in your activity when you create your fragment :

```
ChoosePhoneNumber fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setListener(new FragmentListener() {
    public void refreshData() {
         //Whatever you want to do.
    }
});
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I faced this error message in my MainActivity where I create the fragment:
    fragment = new ChoosePhoneNumber();
       fragment.setListener(new FragmentListener(){
    public void refreshData(){
     
    }
   });
I get this error:
The Method setListener(new ChoosePhoneNumber.FragmentListener(){}) is undefined for the type Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the goal by simply refresh the MainActivity (reload it) again from the ChoosePhoneNumber fragment by adding these two lines at the end of the Fragment:

```
getActivity().finish();
getActivity().startActivity(getActivity().getIntent());
```